# Effects of Increasing number of neurons with relation to the activation function they have

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, nonlinearity

I always thought that information which can be represented by using, say , 8 numbers (the output of 8 neurons in a layer) , need not be mapped onto a 9 or 10 dimensional space as it will occupy an 8-Dimensional subspace of that 9 - dimensional space only.. so it is unnecessary.

But recently , thinking about it again, I found out this :-

The nonlinearity applied to the n-D subspace of (n+1)-D space can represent more functions than the same nonlinearity applied to original n-D space could.

*For some values of n and some nonlinearities. E.g :-

say
n=1 
And nonlinearity -> sine function

Doing linear transformation of 1-D space into 1-D space then applying 
sin ,we get, $sin(w_{1}x_{1})$ as output of this layer (where $w_{1}$ is a scalar and $x_{1}$ is input to the layer.

Doing linear transformation of 1-D space into 2-D space then applying 
sin ,we get, $( sin(w_{1}x_{1}) , sin(w_{2}x_{1}) )$ as output of this layer (where $w$'s are scalars and $x_{1}$ is input to this layer.

Clearly , the two tuple of second case can express more functions when acted upon by consequent layers in the network, than the single number produced in first case.

But , transforming 1-D space into 3-D would not add any extra functions to hypothesis set. So , it is unnecessary according to this logic.

So , my first question :- Is it really unnecessary? Or can it/does it have some use?

Also ,  similar limits (like 2-D for sine) would exist for other non linearities, beyond which we wouldn't be able to add any extra functions to our hypothesis set upon increasing the number of neurons . But some won't have any limit, like ReLU.

Second :- What effect does it have when we increase number of neurons beyond this limit ? Would the optimization(Arriving at the correct weights) become easier or more difficult ?

Third :- What other reasons are there to add more neurons in following layer than were in the previous layer?

Even if you know answer to one of these, or some resource that talks about this, please tell. It'd be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: You would have greater chance of getting your question answered if you cleaned it up a bit. Could you provide reference for the quote you are referring to? You seem to be asking several questions, could you clarify what is your question in here (stick to one question per thread)? Here you can find some more hints https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tim That is not a quote. It is just a sentence written by me which was put in quotation marks, to give emphasis.